# Extending build process with calls to external programs that read ASCII files only

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, character-encoding, msbuild, thrift

I am extending the build process of my project to include generation of new source file from various models (<strike>Thrift IDL</strike> and others). I use C# with Visual Studio 2012.

The generation logic is done by extending `BeforeBuild` target in `.csproj` file as the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Thrift Include="IDL\*.thrift" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(gendirs)"/>
  <MakeDir Directories="$(gendirs)" />
  <XmlPeek XmlInputPath="@(MSBuildProjectDirectory\app.config" Query="/configurations/appSettings/add[@key='ThriftCompilerPath']/@value">
    <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="ThriftExec"/>
  </XmlPeek>
  <Exec Command="$(ThriftExec) -v -out Gen\Thrift --gen csharp:hashcode %(Thrift.FullPath)" />
 ...
</Target>
```

The `.thrift` files are part of the project and are in UTF-8 format which seems to be an issue since the thrift compiler (and others) are not able to process UTF-8 formats and expect only ASCII. Feeding these files to the compiler causes errors.

Is there a way such that the files are either saved in ASCII format or at least converted to ASCII format before feeding them to their corresponding compilers using msbuild? I think this is possible by deriving [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.task.aspx) class but I am looking for *hopefully* simpler solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Thrift understands UTF-8**.

Until recently there was a problem with the BOM preceding some UTF-8 files, so if you store the Thrift IDL file without the BOM, it will work. The problem is [known and already fixed in the Trunk](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2165).

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the information. However the problem persists for other tools :)